# Automatically testing property getters/setters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, properties

We use backing fields for a lot of properties on our domain objects, for example:

```
protected string _firstname;

public virtual string Firstname
{
    get { return _firstname; }
    set { _firstname = value; }
}
```

I've occasionally made stupid typos like the example below, and would like to write a single test that verifies all these properties, rather than manually doing a test per object.

```
public virtual string Firstname
{
    get { return _firstname; }
    set { _firstname = Firstname; }
}
```

Would it be easy to write or does a library already exist to test these backing fields get/set correctly? This would only run on properties with setters and (presumably) a backing field that matches the property name using camel-case underscore

Comment: Have you checked out pex and moles? - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/

Comment: @Luke I have had a play with pex, but haven't had time to use it thoroughly

Comment: Won't your tests which indirectly exercise these properties as part of their execution, catch such bugs ? Do you really need more tests ?

Comment: @Gishu the unit tests did catch this, indirectly, but after stepping through and realising what I've done

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to use automatic properties to eliminate this problem:

```
public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
```

UPDATE (see comments, backing field seems needed):
Another possibility is to generate the pocos. Simple t4-template 'Person.tt'

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<# var pocos = new [] {
    Tuple.Create("FirstName", "string"), 
    Tuple.Create("LastName", "string"), 
    Tuple.Create("Age", "int")}; #>
public partial class Person {
    <# foreach(var t in pocos) {#>

    protected <#= t.Item2#> _<#= t.Item1.ToLowerInvariant()#>;
    public virtual <#= t.Item2#> <#= t.Item1#>
    {
        get { return _<#= t.Item1.ToLowerInvariant()#>; }
        set { _<#= t.Item1.ToLowerInvariant()#> = value; }
    }
    <#}#>
}
```

Now this could of course bring with it as many problems as it solves but it may be worth looking at ... maybe:)

Comment: My question didn't have it originally, but the particular backing fields are protected

Comment: @Chris If you want to prevent editing from outside you can just have the setter be protected. I can't really see any reason why you would want a protected backing field to a public virtual property. What is it you are trying to achieve by having it protected?

Comment: For NHibernate (to elaborate..) they don't necessarily need to be protected however the auto setters won't necessarily match the property name when the compiler generates them

Comment: You are mapping to the backing field? Have you tried mapping to the property instead?

Comment: yep, it causes confusion with NHibernate's proxying so you end up with un-necessary sql statements

Comment: That may be something to pose as a separate question. There are alot of real nhibernate mavens lurking around here.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using auto properties I would think of using reflection to test out my models.. .

Just write a generic method that gets all the properties of your class and then  use methods like these:

```
/ get value of property: public double Number
double value = (double)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(calcInstance, null);

[C#]
// set value of property: public double Number
numberPropertyInfo.SetValue(calcInstance, 10.0, null);
```

For your example:

```
void Main()
{
        const int testValue=5;
    var test = (Test)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test));
    PropertyInfo valuePropertyInfo = typeof(Test).GetProperty("Value");
    valuePropertyInfo.SetValue(test, testValue, null);
    int value = (int)valuePropertyInfo.GetValue(test, null);
    Console.Write(value);   //Assert here instead

}
public class Test
{
private int _value;
public int Value {get {return _value;}  set{_value=Value;}}
}
```

the output of the above function is 0 instead of a 5 which is expected. asserting here would have thrown an error.

What do you think about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

[**Gallio/MbUnit**](http://gallio.org) has a [contract verifier](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit:contract_verifiers) which does exactly what you are looking for. A typical usage of [**AccessContract**](http://gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_ContractVerifiers_AccessorContract_2.htm) is the following:

```
public class Foo // Dummy reference type.
{
  private readonly int value;
  public int Value { get { return value; } }

  public Foo (int value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

public class Bar
{
  private Foo foo;

  public Bar(string unusedParameter) { }

  public Foo Foo // A complex property to be tested!
  {
    get { return foo; }
    set
    {
      if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
      if (value.Value < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
      if (value.Value == 666)
        throw new ArgumentException("Inferno value strictly forbidden.");

      foo = value;
    }
  }
}
```

And the test fixture which uses AccessorContract to run various tests on the property.

```
[TestFixture]
public class BarTest
{
  [VerifyContract]
  public readonly IContract AccessorTests = new AccessorContract<Bar, Foo>
  {
      Getter = target => target.Foo,
      Setter = (target, value) => target.Foo = value,
      ValidValues = { new Foo(123), new Foo(456), new Foo(789) },
      AcceptNullValue = false,
      DefaultInstance = () => new Bar("Hello"),
      InvalidValues =
      {
          { typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException), new Foo(-123), new Foo(-456) },
          { typeof(ArgumentException), new Foo(666) }
      }
  };
}
```

The contract verifier generates the following unit tests:

[image]

Have a look at the [MbUnit test project](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/trunk/v3/src/MbUnit/MbUnit.Tests/Framework/ContractVerifiers/AccessorContractTest.cs) for more usage examples.